# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

```
update publisher_info
set u_code = u_code
where publisher_info.id = unique_code.id;
```

Comment: What's the full error?

Comment: that error message does not relate to the given query. there is no "from unique_code" in the given query!

Comment: I am trying this in phpmyadmin and my first table name is publisher_info and second table name is unique_code. I want to transfer u_code coloumn data from unique_code table to publisher_info table.I am new in sql so plz help me

Comment: sorry my query is

Comment: SELECT u_code
FROM publisher_info
INNER JOIN unique_code
ON publisher_info.id = unique_code.id;

INSERT INTO publisher_info ( 
    u_code ) 
SELECT u_code
     
FROM unique_code WHERE 
publisher_info.id = unique_code.id

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the second table `unique_code` :

```
update publisher_info 
set u_code = (SELECT u_code FROM unique_code
              where publisher_info.id = unique_code.id);
```

Or a join :

```
update publisher_info 
JOIN unique_code
 ON publisher_info.id = unique_code.id
set publisher_info.u_code = unique_code.u_code
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not my sort of expertise :)